# Seamless upgrading of content query web parts

Tags: upgrade, content-query-web-part

Is there a tool or check list for upgrading content query web parts in 2007 to 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a tool to migrate 2007 Content Query WebParts (webpart itself & XSLts). The only thing you will encounter is that the 'slots' within the ItemStyle.xsl will stay empty because you need to fill in those afterwards in the CQWP edit property pane (presentation slots). If you can't/won't do this manually you can create a script (console app for instance) to fill in those slots - to map the appropriate fields (presentation slots) to the itemStyle.xsl slots.

Comment: hi sven. thought it would end up a customization on our part. thanks.